# pass value using jquery to sql parameter in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i want to get value from textbox using jquery and pass it in value in sql parameter in c# web application ?

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){
$("#txt_name").keyup(function(){
alert($(this).val());
});})</script>
```

what i can write instead of alert , keyup function

Comment: yes learn ajax/json, check this if you need some info http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery.post() to send that data back to your web app

Answer (score 0):

You can use FormCollection object on server side to get value like txt_name.